# Requirement aws athena can i get the storage size and row count of the particular table with passing its name

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, metadata, amazon-athena

I'm having a requirement i want to get the table storage size and record count for tables in aws athena, where i don't have the access of tables but i do have the access of metadata tables.Can i get the storage size and row count of the particular table with passing its name.

i have gone through the athena api documentation didnt find what as per my requirement.

Comment: Amazon Athena uses Amazon S3 for storage. If you want to determine the "table storage size", look at the location in S3 where the data is stored. The Row Count would only be accessible by querying the table and that requires permission to read the objects in S3.